# Parametric to Cartesian form

Tags: calculus

when converting parametric equations to cartesian form for the problem

$$ x = \sec^2(t) - 1 , y = \tan(t) ,  -\frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2} $$

I have gotten two answers and would like to know which is the correct answer:

1) $$ x - y^2 = 0 $$ because I squared the y function and used trig identities to get $$ \tan^2(t) = \sec^2(t) - 1$$ and then subtracted x and y.

but then I tried a different method and got:

2) $$ x = y^2 $$ through the same trig identity as above.

Can anyone explain to me which is the proper answer to the question and why? Thank you!

Comment: $x-y^2=0$ is the same as $x=y^2$ !

Comment: Not sure if I've missed something, but $x-y^2=0\Rightarrow x=y^2$ and vice versa?

Comment: @Azif00 Oh my god the simplest things always get me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

$x-y^2=0$ and $x=y^2$ are basically the same thing. Unless you're explicitly told to write $x$ in terms of $y$, or to write your answer on the form $f(x,y)=0$, or something along those lines, they are entirely interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x = \sec^{2}t - 1 = \tan^{2}t = y^{2}.$$

Also, I think you may want $\frac{\pi}{2} < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, as $\sec t$ is not defined at $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}.$